# C++ Instances VS pointers VS references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, instance

I've a program which creates many instances of my own Class. Then I operate them: read, change, pass them to some third party methods etc.

There are three questions.

1. Do I store an vector of instances or a vector of pointers? Why?
2. If I **do not** want to change an instance do I pass to the function an instances or pointers to it? Why?
3. If I **do** want to change an instance, do I pass a pointer or a reference? Why?

Thanks in advance!

Class example:

```
class Player {
    public:
        static const char               width = 35;
        static const char               height = 5;
        static const char               speed = 15;

        int                             socketFD;
        float                           xMin;
        float                           xMax;

        char                            status;
        float                           x;
        float                           y;
        char                            direction;

                                        Player ( int );
        void                            Reset();
        void                            Move();
        void                            SetHost();
        void                            SetClient();

    private:
        void                            EscapeCheck();
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I store an array of instances or an array of pointers? Why?

In case your object is big (i.e. more than 2-3 primitive types) you'd want to store a array of pointers to dynamically allocated instances. This will make reordering objects and resizing/reallocating the container much faster. If you are making use of polymorphism, you pretty much have to use pointers (note that references are also polymorphic) to the base class. This will prevent slicing, since all elements of an array must be the same size, so if you want to store multiple objects, pointers to the base class are the way to go.

The cases where you might prefer storing the instances in the container is if you have a single type (no inheritance and polymorphism) and it is not that big (i.e. a few primitive member types). For bigger objects you might want to use a linked list instead of an array, in order to avoid costly inserts and reallocations.

> If i do not want to change an instance do I pass to the function an
>   instances or pointers to it? Why?

Pass a pointer to constant object or constant reference. Unless you are passing a primitive, where you can simply pass a cheap copy and avoid the modification of the original object.
Whether it is a pointer to const object or a const reference is up to your usage scenario, references are easier to work with, like with normal instances, but cannot be changed to reference to other objects as pointers can.

> If i do want to change an instance, do i pass a pointer or a
>   reference? Why?

If you intend to change the instance, then pass either a pointer or a reference. Which one of the two - see above. This way you can directly modify the particular instance. You can also pass by value, but it will create one temporary copy, which you will later need to assign back to the original object. There is no point in doing that, and if modification is your intent, always go for pointers or references. Even if you don't intend to modify an object, it is still much cheaper to pass a constant pointer or reference, since those are the size of an int, whereas the object might be significantly bigger, so there is no point copying it. If you are passing a primitive type, you might as well pass by value, although if you intend to modify the object, you still have one extra assignment which is avoidable.

Comment: thank you for a reply. I have no polymorphism in my class, but it contains many variables. You say, I should store pointers to access the objects faster, right? I've updated the question btw...

Comment: Other guys say I should store instances... Who do I believe?

Comment: In fact I use a vector... Does it change anything?

Comment: @Kolyunya - your class is not that big, most members are either static or methods, static members are not per instance. If you use a fixed size array and do not plan to to add more elements / resize it, then go for an array of instances.

Comment: @Kolyunya - if you add more objects to the vector, it will eventually run out of capacity and will reallocate itself, if you have many objects reallocation might take a long time, you can minimize that by using pointers instead of instances. You have to test depending on your usage scenario. Seeing how it looks like it is game objects, you could probably get away with storing instances, I doubt you will store millions of them.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. The disadvantage of storing objects is - it may take long time to reallocate the vector, if there are **many** objects.

Comment: @Kolyunya - well, there are many. For starters, pointers are somewhat dangerous, especially if you don't know what you are doing. Then - pointers infer that you are using dynamic memory allocation, which is slower and has some memory overhead, a vector of x objects will use MUCH LESS memory than a vector of x pointers plus the actual dynamically allocated objects. When you allocate memory dynamically, the OS will almost always give you a little more than you need, plus there is a small header for this memory fragment that uses memory too. IN SHORT - only use pointers when toy NEED TO use them!

Comment: Thanks in advance, mate! So, you advice me to use a rule: "If you can use objects - use objects". Right? This means "Use pointers if it is the **ONLY** way to go". Do I understand you correct?

Comment: @Kolyunya - well yes, but choosing between pointers and instances is not the only option, for bigger objects you may chose to use a list or a deque, which allow very fast insert/reorder and don't need reallocation t all, but have some other drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks! @ddriver I will very appreciate if you answer, if the following code is a _good_style_ to add an instance of a class to a vector, 'cause I'm a newbie in C++... Is it the way to go? `Player * player = new Player(socketFD); this->players.push_back (*player);'

Comment: Yes, but considering the `new` operator returns a pointer to the allocated object you can just `push_back(new Player(socketFD))` and it should work, and save yourself one assignment.

Comment: You did not get the idea. I decided to follow your rule and add **objects**, not **pointers**. So i will need to convert (I don't know how it's called) pointer to object using `*`. That is what second line does.

Comment: @Kolyunya - well, in that case DON'T USE the `new` keyword, you don't need that, just create a local `Player` and push_back it - it will be copied into the array. There is no point of creating a pointer, allocating the object dynamically and dereferencing the pointer to get the object reference. Without `delete`, the `new Player()` you create is not being deleted and remains a memory leak that will build up every time you run that method. A local/automatic Player will be automatically deleted when it runs out of method scope.

Comment: @Kolyunya - or simply `push_back(Player(socketFD));`

Answer (score 6):

> Do I store an array of instances or an array of pointers? Why?

If `Class` is a base class, and you want to prevent object slicing, you store pointers. Otherwise, objects.

> If i do not want to change an instance do I pass to the function an instances or pointers to it? Why?

If you pass by value, you don't modify the original object because you're working on a copy. If you pass a pointer or a reference, you mark it as const:

```
void foo ( MyClass const* );
void foo ( MyClass const& );
```

> If i do want to change an instance, do i pass a pointer or a reference? Why?

Either. I personally prefer references, pointers are more tightly connected to dynamic allocation.

Nowadays, RAII is often used, so an excellent alternative is to use smart pointers instead.

Comment: `if Class is a base class, and you want to prevent object slicing, you store pointers`... And if a `Class` is designed by me and consists of two strings and two integers for example?

Comment: @Kolyunya do you use it as a base class? Is it polymorphic?

Comment: I do not really know what is a `base` class at the moment. It's just a class with a number of constants, variables, methods. Lets say, it is **not** polymorphic. And what does it change if it **is**?

Comment: @Kolyunya for example, if you have class B derived from class A and a vector of A objects, if you insert B objects in the vector, they will be sliced. Polymorphism won't work any more.

Comment: In the debate pointers vs references, the rule of thumb is: 'Use references where you can and pointers where you have to.'

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I've added the code of the class to the question. As I can see, you advice to store objects. My question is: I first create an onject _somewere_, then copy it to the storage. So I double used memory, right? Isn't it a problem? I use this code `Player* player = new Player ( socketFD ); this->players.push_back ( *player );` Is it ok?

Comment: @Kolyunya no. You can just use `players.push_back(Player(socketFD));`

Answer (score 4):

> Do I store an array of instances or an array of pointers? Why?

This really depends on the use case. Either solution can be OK, depending on context. You may want to store base classes of a polymorphic type, or you might want to avoid copying elements (for example, when dealing with non-copyable types). In these cases, you should store pointers or [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

> If i do not want to change an instance do I pass to the function an instances or pointers to it? Why?

Then you should pass a const reference (reference to a const instance)

```
void foo(const Foo& f);
```

> If i do want to change an instance, do i pass a pointer or a reference? Why?

Then you should pass a non-const reference (reference to a non-const instance). This assumes you really want to change an existing instance:

```
void foo(Foo& f);
```

But when would you use pointers then? Then only case I can think of right now is when there is a possibility for the passed entity to have an invalid or null value. With references this is impossible, or at least not trivial to implement. Pointers can be set to `0`, `NULL` (the same) or `nullptr` in C++11.

```
void (Foo* f) {
  if (f) {
    // do something with pointee
  } else {
    // deal with it
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For number two, it kind of depends. Most efficient would probably be to pass a constant reference instead.

And generally, try to avoid pointers as much as possible. If you *have* to use pointers, use the [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Answer (score 1):

1. Array of instances is better because you save on the pointer itself plus on the allocation block header. (Provided that array is fine for your needs).

2,3 In bothy cases it is better to pass refrerences. In the second case const ref. The advantage is saving on not calling ctors.

Comment: And if the object is larger than that (most probably it is)?

Comment: I had real situations when space, occupied by pointers was not negligible. This is not an every day scenario, but may happen.

Comment: @Gorpik you're comparing the space occupied by a pointer with the space occupied by a full object? Indirection is not an issue, direct access or access by pointer are the same

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You have to construct the object all the same. The only space difference is the size of the pointer.

Comment: @Gorpik you do know a vector makes copies of the object, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: As for indirection: accessing the pointer and then the object pointed is not the same as accessing the object directly. I think we are not thinking about the same here.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: OK, now I know that we are talking about different things. You are thinking of objects that already exist and then have to be stored in an array; I (and I guess the same goes for Kirill) am thinking of objects that can be created inside an array or as independent instances and then pointed by an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I store an array of instances or an array of pointers? Why?

I would prefer going for array of instances. You will have less of a headache managing memory. If you populate array of pointers dynamically, you may catch OOM at, say, 1000th element - now the program has to cleanup half-formed array. It is better in this sense to preallocate one big chunk in one go.

> If i do not want to change an instance do I pass to the function an instances or pointers to it? Why?
>   If i do want to change an instance, do i pass a pointer or a reference? Why?

I always prefer references, because then you can skip on checking its validity. Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) references can not be NULL, but I could kick NULL-references all around, because behavior is undefined and in my compiler it just happened to be that way. But if you account for that you are really on the dark side of the power. Alternatively, declaring function to accept pointers invites for passing `NULL` and you have to check for it always. There is nice [blog](http://www.gotw.ca/conv/002.htm) describing null references - very good example that changed my mind.

One downside of using references is that you can not say from function call line of code whether function takes argument by value or by reference.

You should remember that references are essentially pointers and reference type has size, so if your `Class` is really small, then you might consider passing objects by value, if you dont want to change them inside function. I would still pass by reference though - `Class` can grow and then you go and fix all prototypes - not nice.

Comment: "Array of instances requires you to have default constructor and assignment operator available in your Class" no...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Why no? Please elaborate. VisualStudio complains error 'C2512: 'A' : no appropriate default constructor available'. Are we speaking of some quirky way of array initialization?

Comment: You can initalize array objects with a non-default constructor, yes. Why is it quirky?

Comment: Yes, you are right: A a[2] = {A(5), A(6)};. Thanks for sharing your wisdom. I did not mean to sound aggressive

Comment: Why worry about passing NULL pointers?  First, you have to actually do it, (ie. there has to be a gross bug in your code), and even then the most likely result is an almost immediate segfault/AV - easily debugged.  Of all the things that can go wrong in apps, passing in a NULL somewhere is below the noise level.

Comment: @MartinJames Because function prototype allows you to do so. This is not always a bug. If NULL pointers are not actually expected, then you place assert, but this is extra effort.